# Do reference to dereferenced NULL pointer produce UB on creation or on access in C++

Tags: c++, reference, null, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to implement code like this

```
if (auto *ptr = get_obj_ptr(), &obj = *ptr; ptr)
{
    // access obj here
}
else
    // handle error without accessing ptr and obj
```

assuming that `get_obj_ptr()` could return either valid pointer to valid object or `NULL`. Is this code legal in C++? Accessing to `obj` if `prt == NULL` is undefined behavior, but do just defining NULL-dereferenced reference also result into UB?

Yes, the only point is the subject of comfort and style, but theoretical subject is also matter. Maybe there is any other elegant and UB-. exception-, and boost-free solution?

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax in the `if`

Comment: @drescherjm, sure, sorry.

Comment: @user4581301 • C++17 added the ability to the [`if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) statement to have an *init-statement* before the *condition* expression.  If you need that syntax, it's very handy (although the workaround isn't terrible, either).

Comment: The UB is on access.  Here's the access that dereferences the pointer:  `*ptr` (as used in the `auto& obj = *ptr`).

Comment: @Eljay It was the comma and the semicolon that got me. Couldn't get it to compile on any compiler I threw it at, but it turned out the error was elsewhere in my test case: https://godbolt.org/z/q7qrss . `else` with no body. The error message in gcc was particularly useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this code legal in C++?

No , it is not legal.

> just defining NULL-dereferenced reference also result into UB?

Yes.

> Maybe there is any other elegant and UB-. exception-, and boost-free solution?

An elegant solution: Bind the reference after checking for nullness:

```
if (auto *ptr = get_obj_ptr())
{
    auto& obj = *ptr; 
    // access obj here
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `auto &obj = *ptr;` incl. `auto` and with the variable name typo fixed?

Comment: @CherryDT Sure :) I wanted to keep it equivalent with the original

Comment: Yes but `auto a = x, b = y;` can't be taken apart without adding another `auto` in front of `b = y`, right?

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks for pointing out. I didn't pay much attention to what I was copying. Fixed now.